# How to save state of checked radio button in android studio

Tags: java, android, radio-button, state

I am using three radio buttons in radio group to select one of theme to perform the theme selection(default ,Light and Dark theme). but when I restart app there will be no one selected . How can I save the state of checked radio button and when I restart the app last checked radio button remain checked. i am attaching screenshot and code here, Please can anyone help me in detail because i am new in android studio.
([Light Theme Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T12yH.jpg)) ([Dark Theme Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apesX.jpg)) ([After restarting app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMNE0.jpg))

xml

```
<RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/system"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Default"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:backgroundTint="@null"
                    android:button="@color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_selector"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_btn_text_color"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/light"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Light"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:backgroundTint="@null"
                    android:button="@color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_selector"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_btn_text_color"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/dark"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dark"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:backgroundTint="@null"
                    android:button="@color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_selector"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_btn_text_color"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            </RadioGroup>
```

Java Code in Fragment

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_appearance_bottom_sheet, container, false);

       // materialButtonToggleGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_group);
       radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);


        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                switch(i) {
                    case R.id.system:

                        break;
                    case R.id.light:
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                        break;
                    case R.id.dark:
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        return  view;
    }
```

Comment: You have to store the data in a persistent way

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference.

```
// Storing data into SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",MODE_PRIVATE);

// Creating an Editor object to edit(write to the file)
SharedPreferences.Editor myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit();
  
// if them is Dark set it to true and when theme is Light set it to false.
   myEdit.putBoolean("savedTheme", true);
   myEdit.apply();

// Now when app is opened check the save value in shared preference
 sharedPreferences.getBoolean("savedTheme", false);
 
 Now on restart of app check
 if it is sharedPreferences value is true then set radio button to Dark else Light.
```

Check this link for more info -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-preferences-in-android-with-examples/